# What do @ and $ do in a Serilog message template parameter?

Tags: c#, serilog

I found some code with log parameters that use the @ sign in front of the name.
`logger.LogError(ex, "Failed to add {@data}", jsonData)`

I'm having trouble finding the docs for what this does exactly. The Serilog doc says this:

> Property names may be prefixed with an optional operator, @ or $, to control how the property is serialised

But it doesn't say what that will do. How does `{@data}` differ from `{data}` in a log message template?

Comment: Did you look at this documentation? https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Structured-Data

Comment: No. I had not found that. That's perfect and it answers the question. Please post this as the answer if like. I'll upvote and accept it.

Comment: also recommend reading https://serilog.net/ - it covers key stuff really neatly, including this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is some documentation on these operators [here](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Structured-Data) (also
accessible via [serilog.net](https://serilog.net/)).

- `@` is the *destructuring* operator
- `$` is the *stringification* operator